# Setting Up Connected React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, connected-react-router

I'm trying to set up connected-react-router according to t[he steps in the README](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router).

I have this current code in my store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers';
import { middleware, runSagas } from './middleware';

const createSWStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducer, middleware);
  runSagas();
  return store;
};

export default createSWStore;
```

I've tried to follow the set up, but I keep getting a `Uncaught TypeError: rootReducer is not a function` error in the browser.

Currently the file looks like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

import reducer from './reducers';
import { middleware, runSagas } from './middleware';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const createSWStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    connectRouter(reducer)(history),
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history),
      ),
    ),
    middleware);
  runSagas();
  return store;
};

export default createSWStore;
```

Comment: Share your reducer file. Are you still getting error ?

Comment: Make sure you are exporting rootReducer from your reducer file. If possible share code for reducer file.

Comment: There isn't a single reducer.js file, there is a folder of "reducers"

Comment: use combine reducers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give connectRouter the `history` instead of the reducer. So:

```
connectRouter(history)(reducer),
```

instead of `connectRouter(reducer)(history)`.

You said that `import reducer from './reducers';` refers to a folder containing the reducers. Assuming that the reducers folder has three files (index.js, reducer1.js and reducer2.js), then having something like this in `reducers` should work:

**Index.js**

```js
import reducer1 from './reducer1';
import reducer2 from './reducer2';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({ reducer1, reducer2 });
```

**reducer1.js**

```js
const reducer1 = (state = { myState: "foo" }, action) => {
    return state;
};

export default reducer1;
```

**reducer2.js**

```js
const reducer2 = (state = { myState: "bar" }, action) => {
    return state;
};

export default reducer2;
```